# get_parent_theme_file_path vs. get_template_directory

Tags: child-theme, template-tags

I've been reading about the new functions for [referencing theme location](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/09/09/new-functions-hooks-and-behaviour-for-theme-developers-in-wordpress-4-7/) added in v4.7.

I read through the [trac ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18302). 
I understand why they created these functions and the benefit of `get_theme_file_path()` for use in child themes. But aside from verbal clarity is there a specific reason to use `get_parent_theme_file_path()` over `get_template_directory()` when referencing files in the parent theme?

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a specific reason to use get_parent_theme_file_path() over
>   get_template_directory()

Yes. This new function comes with a filter

- Filter parent_theme_file_path
- And argument to the file path

If you take a look at the [get_parent_theme_file_path()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_parent_theme_file_path/#source) source, it's just returning `get_template_directory()` with extra functionality like if a file is given as an argument to the `get_parent_theme_file_path` it returns path to the file and it also comes `parent_theme_file_path` filter which is very good to override.

`get_parent_theme_file_path` is introduced for consistency and to allow child themes to override easily. I don't see any point not to use this instead of `get_template_directory`.

I wrote a [post](https://bravokeyl.com/get-theme-file-uri-and-get-theme-file-path/) on these functions, that can be helpful.

**Use case:**

Suppose you are including a file in the theme using `get_template_directory` like the following.

```
include(get_template_directory().'/inc/bk.php'); /*../themes/bk-theme/inc/bk.php */
```

and if you want to override `bk.php` in the child theme it's not **possible**

If you include the same file with the new function

```
include(get_parent_theme_file_path('inc/bk.php')); /*../bk-theme/inc/bk.php */
```

You can easily override this file inclusion in the child theme using `parent_theme_file_path` like the following

```
add_filter('parent_theme_file_path','bk_257597_parent_theme_file',10,2);
function bk_257597_parent_theme_file($path,$file){
 if('inc/bk.php' == $file) {
  //do something
  $file = 'my-file';
  $path = 'my-path'.$file;
 }
 return $path;
}
```